# calling $PWD from another script

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, pwd

Having some trouble getting $PWD to work inside a bash script...

I have two scripts in the same directory:

`~/outer.sh, ~/inner.sh`.  I use `outer.sh` to call `inner.sh` as follows:

(outer.sh contents shown below)

```
#!/bin/bash

$PWD/inner.sh
```

But this seems not to work.  Further investigation shows that $PWD appears inaccessible as I've used it here (nothing appears with `printf $PWD >> logfile.txt`), and I suspect it has something to do with calling a script from a script... can anyone clarify what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$PWD` is the current directory, not the directory containing the script. There's no reason why `inner.sh` would be located in the current directory.

The path to the script is stored in `$0`. You can extract its directory part to find the directory containing the script.

```
script_directory=$(dirname -- "$0")
"$script_directory/inner.sh"
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within